# Django Model Form No POST Data

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-users

I've seen other questions on Stack Overflow similar to this one yet very different so please don't be so quick to vote to close. Essentially, I've been trying to make a very simple login form following the techniques I've found on every tutorial online. For some reason, filling and submitting the form does not return any POST request data. Here is my code:

View

```
def signon(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = SignOnForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)

            logger.info(user)

            return HttpResponse('Username: {} Password {}'.format(username, password))

        return HttpResponse("Error {}".format(request.POST))

    if request.method == 'GET':

        form = SignOnForm()

        return render(request, 'signon.html', {'form': form})
```

Template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <title>Sign into Account</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form method = "POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <input type = "submit" value = "Sign In">
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Form

```
class SignOnForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:

        model = User

        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

I'm using the `User` class provided by Django, and for some reason upon submitting the completed form, no POST data is returned and hence why `is_valid` always fails. Any ideas?

Comment: where is your action in the form template?

Comment: I tried using the action `"/signon/"` but it didn't do anything

Comment: Well I tried your code and the POST data is correctly received. And `is_valid` does not fail

Comment: So you're getting the page with the username and password in the response?

Comment: Yeap. That's right. What does it show you? What does `return HttpResponse("Error {}".format(request.POST))` shows?

Comment: So ... looking in the DOM inspector I actually see a `querydict` element containing all the keys of the request. I just don't know why it won't actually render in the response and why the form is determined to be invalid.

Comment: You can check why form is invalid. Try to print `form.errors` and that will give you the errors which occurred in  the form

Comment: A user with that username already exists. What? I'm just trying to sign in, Django. I know it exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've discovered the issue. Model forms expect to persist data once completed. So this form was unsuccessfully trying to create a duplicate user with an existing user name and that was the error it was facing.

What was the solution? Inherit from `forms.Form` instead of `forms.ModelForm` and manually list the username and password fields. You shouldn't attach a model to your form so as to avoid this error. This may be a new feature in the latest release because I've never seen it.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your view somewhat like this,

```
def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignOnForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('url of some page')
            return HttpResponse("Error {}".format(form.errors)
    else:
        form = SignOnForm()
    return render(request, 'signon.html', dict(form=form))
```

Comment: Again, if the form is invalid the statements under the condition do not matter.